# script inside iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am running this script:

```
<div id="test"> 
                <iframe 
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.paymentwall.com/brick/brick.1.4.js"></script>
                    <script>
                    var brick = new Brick({
                        public_key: '',
                        amount: 9.99,
                        currency: 'EUR',
                        container: test,
                        action: 'test.php',
                        form: {
                            merchant: 'Test',
                            product: 'Test',
                            pay_button: 'Pay',
                            zip: true
                        }
                              });

                    brick.showPaymentForm(function(data) {
                    //handle success
                    }, function(errors) {
                    //handle errors
                    });
                </script>
                </iframe>
                </div>
```

to process payments. However, when I load the certain page it is blank - blank body and blank head.

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood the concept of iframes. The content between opening and closing tags is parsed only, if a browser doesn't support iframes. If you want to execute a script in an iframe, you've to place/link it to the document you're going to show (use `src` attribute to specify the URL) in the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). See also [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element).

Answer (score 2):

You have to close iframe (>) You forgot the first one.
Also the action is missing this (')

Comment: Tried to add > after <iframe with no success. The ' after action is there.

Comment: Teemu did some good comment on your post, didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.paymentwall.com/brick/brick.1.4.js"></script>
                <script>
                var brick = new Brick({
                    public_key: '',
                    amount: 9.99,
                    currency: 'EUR',
                    container: 'test',
                    action: 'test.php',
                    form: {
                        merchant: 'Test',
                        product: 'Test',
                        pay_button: 'Pay',
                        zip: true
                    }
                          });

                brick.showPaymentForm(function(data) {
                //handle success
                }, function(errors) {
                //handle errors
                });

    document.getElementById('my_iframe').onload = brick();
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"> 
            <iframe id="my_iframe">

            </iframe>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```